# Tensorflow invalid shape (InvalidArgumentError)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow2.0

model.fit produces exception:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot update variable with shape [] using a Tensor with shape [32], shapes must be equal.
         [[{{node metrics/accuracy/AssignAddVariableOp}}]]
         [[loss/dense_loss/categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_50/_63]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_1408]
```

Model definition:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(
        input_shape=(360, 7)
    ))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(360, 7)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(512, 1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1048, 1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax'))
```

Input Features Shape

```
(105, 360, 7)
```

Input Labels Shape

```
(105, 32, 1)
```

Compile statement

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Model.fit statement

```
 model.fit(features,
              labels,
              epochs=50000,
              validation_split=0.2,
              verbose=1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Try changing the shape of `labels` to `(105,32)` by `np.squeeze(labels)`.

Comment: @giser_yugang wow thanks, that seem like it worked. Could you explain why? Create reply and I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `model.summary()` to see your model architecture.

```
print(model.summary())

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 360, 32)           256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 360, 32)           1056      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 120, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 120, 512)          16896     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 120, 1048)         537624    
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d (Gl (None, 1048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                33568     
=================================================================
Total params: 589,400
Trainable params: 589,400
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The shape of your output layer is required to be `(None,32)`, but the shape of your `labels` is `(105,32,1)`. So you need to change the shape to `(105,32)`. `np.squeeze()` function is used when we want to remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flatten() before the Dense Layers.